# Using sms otp with authentication (oidc) in IdentityServer4 and Dotnet Core Identity

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Identity Server 4 and Dotnet Core Identity for authentication service. Authentication service has custom react spa.

I'm trying to get started a authenticate a user using their mobile number. I have a user data (email, password, phone number, etc.) 
I want this steps;

1. User:Key in email and password (done)
2. Server:Send sms with code to mobile number (?), i have a sms server
3. User:Key-in code from SMS
4. Server:Send access token (done)

I developed a project using this example. https://github.com/karpikpl/identity-server4-with-SPA-UI

I have no idea how to integrate two factors, how can I help you?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this issue can be like this:

**Step 1**
Generate an SMS code in your IDP (Auth server).

**Step 2**
Store that SMS code as a claim for the user with an expiration time (if needed).

**Step 3**
When the user comes to sign in to your IDP using his username, you can compare the entered SMS code by the user with that one you stored in DB as a user claim. Also, you may want to check the expiration time of the SMS code.

**Step 4**
If everything was ok so you remove that claim of the user then log him into your IDP and done.

Comment: There is a question. how can i get generated OTP to send?
As you may be know the OTP code will be compared in LoginWith2fa action in IDS4 via SignInmManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(...). In my Scenario i want to Send it via SMS.

Comment: You have it as a claim of the user, as I said in the answer.

Comment: I don't want to generate any code.
I want to have the code (google Authenticator) will be compared.

Comment: You can use libraries that are already created. Also your need can be asked in the form of a new question to be answered.

Comment: https://nugetmusthaves.com/tag/TOTP

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-sms-otp/